# Complex numbers - locus of a point

Tags: complex-numbers

**Question:**

> If $z \neq 1$ and ${z^2} \over {z-1}$ is real, then find the locus of the point represented by the complex number $z$.

I'm not sure how to approach this question. I attempted to substitute $z = x + iy$, however, that didn't solve the problem. It's quite clear, by observation, that any point on the real axis would satisfy the equation. However, there also have to be some other points. How would I approach this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\dfrac{z^2}{z-1}=z+1+\dfrac1{z-1}$$ will be real iff $z-1+\dfrac1{z-1}$ is real

Set $z-1=w$

Now $w+\dfrac1w$ is real $\iff w+\dfrac1w=\bar w+\dfrac1{\bar w}$

$(w-\bar w)\dfrac{w\bar w-1}{w\bar w}=0$

If $w-\bar w=0, w=\bar w\implies w$ is real $\iff z$ is real

Else $w\bar w-1=0\iff1=w\bar w=|w|^2$

Comment: Elegant answer!

Answer (score 3):

Let $\displaystyle z=x+iy$ in $\displaystyle \frac{z^2}{z-1} = \frac{(x+iy)^2}{x+iy-1} = \frac{x^2-y^2+2ixy}{(x-1)+iy}\times \frac{(x-1)-iy}{(x-1)-iy}$

So we get $\displaystyle \frac{(x^2-y^2)(x-1)+2xy^2+i\left[-y(x^2-y^2)++2xy(x-1)\right]}{(x-1)^2+y^2}$

$\displaystyle  = \frac{(x^2-y^2)(x-1)+2xy^2}{(x-1)^2+y^2}+i\frac{2xy(x-1)-y(x^2-y^2)}{(x-1)^2+y^2}$

so put $\displaystyle \frac{2xy(x-1)-y(x^2-y^2)}{(x-1)^2+y^2} = 0\Rightarrow 2xy(x-1)-y(x^2-y^2) =0$

So we get $\displaystyle y\left[2x^2-2x-x^2+y^2\right] = 0\Rightarrow y[x^2+y^2-2x] =0$

So $y=0$ or $x^2+y^2-2x=0$

Comment: Soory daniel I have edited it.

Answer (score 1):

Using If ${z'}$ is real  Then $z'=\bar{z'}$

So Let $$\displaystyle z'=\frac{z^2}{z-1}\;,$$ Then $$\displaystyle \frac{z^2}{z-1} = \upperbrace{\left(\frac{z^2}{z-1}\right)} = \frac{\bar{z}^2}{\bar{z}-1}$$

So we get $$\displaystyle \displaystyle \frac{z^2}{z-1} = \frac{\bar{z}^2}{\bar{z}-1}$$

So $$\displaystyle z^2\bar{z}-z^2 = \bar{z}^2z-\bar{z}^2\Rightarrow \left(z^2\bar{z}-z\bar{z}^2\right)-(z^2-\bar{z}^2) =0$$

so we get $$\displaystyle z\bar{z}(z-\bar{z})-(z+\bar{z})\cdot (z-\bar{z}) =0$$

So we get $$\displaystyle (z-\bar{z})\cdot \left[z\bar{z}-(z+\bar{z})\right] =0$$

So we get $$z-\bar{z} =0$$ or $z\bar{z}-(z+\bar{z})=0$$

Now Put $z=x+iy$ and $\bar{z} = x-iy\;,$ means $z+\bar{z} = 2x$ and $z-\bar{z}=2iy$

and $z\bar{z} = x^2+y^2$

So we get $$2iy=0\Rightarrow y=0$$ or  $$x^2+y^2-2x =0$$